# Array value is truncated to one digit

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm using PHP to create dynamic checkboxes. According to my the Chrome elements inspector the values echo with no problem, but at some point after $_POST all my values are truncated to one digit.

Checkboxes for 12 hues with input values 1~12 echo'd↴

```
// Dynamically create checkboxes from database
function print_checkbox($db){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM hue_flag') as $row) {
        if ($i == 0 || $i == 3 || $i== 6 || $i == 9){
            echo '<br><br>';
        }
        $i++;
        echo '<span class="'.$row['1'].'"><label for="'.$row['1'].'">'.ucfirst($row['1']).'</label><input type="checkbox" name="hue[]" class="hue" value="'.$row['0'].'"></span> ';
    }
}
```

When I check my database values 10, 11, and 12 have been truncated to 1.

Code for INSERTion↴

```
// Above this comment: INSERT to table gown; Below this comment: INSERT to table gown_hues
$insertId = $conn->lastInsertId();

if(is_array($_POST['hue'])){
    foreach($_POST['hue'] as $key => $hue){
        $insertSQLToGown_Hues = sprintf("INSERT INTO gown_hues (`gown_id`, `hue_id`) VALUES (".$insertId.", ".$hue['0'].")");
        $conn->query($insertSQLToGown_Hues);
    }
}
else {
    $insertSQLToGown_Hues = sprintf("INSERT INTO gown_hues (`gown_id`, `hue_id`) VALUES (".$insertId.", ".$hue.")");
    $conn->query($insertSQLToGown_Hues);
}
```

What is going on and where is it happening?!

Answer (score 3):

You're in a foreach loop so `$hue` is a string, not an array.

`$hue['0']` is treating the string as an array of characters and so returns the first character

Also, since you're only getting an array of values, not a list of key/value pairs, your foreach could simply be...

```
foreach($_POST['hue'] as $hue){
    $insertSQLToGown_Hues = sprintf("INSERT INTO gown_hues (`gown_id`, `hue_id`) VALUES (".$insertId.", ".$hue.")");
    $conn->query($insertSQLToGown_Hues);
}
```

Note that you're not even attempting to make sure that the values passed to you are sanitised which means you're susceptible to SQL Injection - what happens if someone modifies your form so that instead of a numeric `hue_id`, they posted `1); DROP TABLE gown_hues--`?

```
$insertSQLToGown_Hues = sprintf("INSERT INTO gown_hues (`gown_id`, `hue_id`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($insertId)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($hue)."')");
```

would be a step in the right direction but using parameterised queries is even better.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood how [] works. So, I don't actually need my if, else, right?

Regarding sanitation, learning that was next on my To do list.

Comment: When I changed the code as you suggested, no values were inserted to gown_hues.

Comment: In fact, now that I think about it, your code is the way I had it yesterday. I couldn't figure out why the values weren't being inserted, so I changed it to what is posted in my question, because I thought I needed it to be an array. I thought the 0 referred to the 0th column of my MySQL table.

Comment: Never mind. I am an idiot. They have been inserting all along, my number of rows displayed was set to 30, so I didn't see them. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, glad we pointed you in the right direction :) The SQL injection bit is important though - do update your scripts as appropriate and read up on parameterised queries

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['hue'] as $key => $hue){
        $insertSQLToGown_Hues = sprintf("INSERT INTO gown_hues (`gown_id`, `hue_id`) VALUES (".$insertId.", ".$hue['0'].")");
        $conn->query($insertSQLToGown_Hues);
    }
```

Should be: (You always insert the first element of the array, instead of the $hue retrieved from the array in the loop)

```
foreach($_POST['hue'] as $key => $hue){
        $insertSQLToGown_Hues = sprintf("INSERT INTO gown_hues (`gown_id`, `hue_id`) VALUES (".$insertId.", ".$hue.")");
        $conn->query($insertSQLToGown_Hues);
    }
```